# What causing Android Device Asus Zenfone 2 alarm manager not working?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have develop an android app, and running well on all devices, except Asus Zeofone 2, I have the AlarmManager does not working to fire my Service ?

Does anybody have same problem ?

Regards,
Steve

Comment: Please add some code, maybe it can help. Do you get any errors in your log?

Comment: Define `not working`

Comment: I have the same problem!! with Huawei too!!!

Answer (score 3):

Check the Asus' preloaded Auto-start Manager app. It automatically denies some apps' alarm service.

Comment: You made my day. I think this is happening to a lot of people. same for me, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44415369/6548766)