# BroadcastReceiver dies with app

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

If i let the phone sit for a long time like 15 minutes i lose my receiver but i thought it was to persist like a service after being killed for memory.

Manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".WearableReceiver"
    android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.johnbravado.MESSAGE_PROCESSED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In Activity to start receiver

```
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(CounterActivity.this, WearableReceiver.class);
getPackageManager()
    .setComponentEnabledSetting(component,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

The receiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
    //MyConstants.getInstance().showToast("Message Rcvd");
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "com.example.johnbravado");
    wakeLock.acquire();
    // Do Work
    MyConstants.getInstance().msgReqAction(intent.getIntExtra(MyConstants.BROADCAST_DATA_REQ, 0));

    wakeLock.release();
}
```

The broadcast sender

```
String BROADCAST_ACTION_RESP = "com.example.johnbravado.MESSAGE_PROCESSED"
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    nodeId = messageEvent.getSourceNodeId();
    String incomingPath = messageEvent.getPath();
    int incomingReq = Integer.parseInt(new String(messageEvent.getData()));

    if(incomingPath.equalsIgnoreCase(MyConstants.MSG_COUNTER_REQ_PATH)) {
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION_RESP);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(MyConstants.BROADCAST_DATA_REQ, incomingReq);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    }else if(incomingPath.equalsIgnoreCase(MyConstants.MSG_DEFAULT_PATH)){

    }
}
```

only way I get this to persist for long periods of time is to invoke a service

```
wearableReceiverIntent = new Intent(this, WearableReceiverService.class);
if(!WearableReceiverService.isRunning())
    startService(wearableReceiverIntent);
```

the service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MyConstants.BROADCAST_ACTION_RESP);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    receiver = new WearableReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif_bible)
        .setContentText("Preaching").build();
startForeground(MyConstants.NOTIF_COUNTING_SERVICE, notification);

    isRunning = true;
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

If I run the service it persists for long periods of time but it drains the battery unnecessarily considering I interact only once every 10 minutes. I was under impression Broadcast receiver would work like service except for short bursts of work. invoke the service if you need to do long actions.

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "i lose my receiver" means and how you determined this.

Comment: it no longer performs the act within onReceived of the receiver.

Comment: When/how are you disabling the component via `PackageManager`? Also, are you positively sure that `onReceive()` is NOT being called after 15 minutes? How did you verify that?

Comment: i have a start() and a stop(). inside the start(), I enable the receiver and the service I want to run using the above code. In the stop(), i disable it. I believe it is not being called because up until android kills it for memory it is working fine. better test would be to output to a log file to see if i enter it. But i do not know how to access those log files. unless that is what logcat apps are for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greenify was killing my app when the screen went off. I was battling something I had no hope of defending against with code. After I explicitly told Greenify to not kill my app, I never told it to kill my app to begin with, everything worked as intended.

Answer (score 1):

A [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle) handles an intent and then stops again. This handling of an intent should be fast. If you want to do a lot of stuff, you should start an `Service` from the `BroadcastReceiver` and handle it from there.

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call
>   to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this
>   function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer
>   active.

A BroadcastReceiver is started using the `sendBroadcast` intent.
So remove `android:enabled="false"` and use `sendBroadcast`, which will startup the Receiver by Android.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: I send broadcast correctly, since app works as intended so long as phone is awake and app is running and not killed. It doesnt need ot be in foreground just not dead. Also i turn the reciever on and off via the powermanager so that it is not always running since i do not need that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem due on my **Asus ZenPad** due to the Asus Mobile Manager app, specifically the "Auto start manager" was blocking the intent to my app.

Deactivating the app (uninstall is not possible) worth nothing, the solution has been to leave the app installed but whitelist my developing app so it can receive broadcast like PACKAGE_REPLACE. (Pay attention that the switches are confusing, you actually have to touch on "blocked" so it turns on into "allowed" to enable it.

I think another option is to update or change the ROM (choosing one without all that bloatware).

Answer (score 0):

If your `BroadcastReceiver` is setup in your manifest, there is no need to try and adjust the `PackageManager` component information for your package.  As long as you remove the `enabled="false"` part.

Your `BroadcastReceiver` should be very short with what it does: typically update some internal data or start another component which can do the heavy lifting of your app's operation.  You can use it to trigger a `Service` to do this type of thing in the background.  But, note that "background" in this case means without user-interaction.  It *does not mean* a background context of execution, such as a secondary thread.  It is up to you do manage the thread(s) in your `Service`.  Your `BroadcastReceiver` and `Service` callback entry points (`onReceive()` and `onStartIntent()`) run in the context of the *main thread* of your app.

Power management definitely plays a roll in all of this.  Is your broadcast `Intent` actually being sent and done in a way which will wake the device?  If it does wake the device and send the `Intent`, the device will only stay awake long enough for the `BroadcastReceiver` to run its `onReceive()`; after that returns there are no guarantees.  The device will aggressively sleep, which is why wakelocks are a thing.  However, use of wakelocks can cause excessive battery drain, unless used properly.  If you are running on Marshmallow or newer, the Doze functionality can also wreck havoc on your plans.  Wakelocks are ignored when in Doze mode and won't be considered until the user brings the device out of doze.

Comment: I set enabled="false" and used power manager because i dont want it to listen all the time. only when i activate it in the main app. So rather then doing a check `isItWorking()' i just wanted to enable/disable the receiver period.

i am merely trying to update a shared preference. I added a code snippet to show how i send broadcast and i know it works because if app is active and not been killed it works as intended. It is only when the device "sleeps" or kills my app that i lose functionality. So you may be right on i am not sending intent in a way to wake device.

Comment: The problem with manually manipulating the enable flag is that if your app is killed, or marked the component as disabled when the device sleeps, the system has no way of knowing it needs to wake up or start your app. With the receiver registered in the manifest, the system knows when it needs to start your app, even if it had been killed. What you are doing is roughly equivalent to calling `registerReceiver()`.

Comment: Fair enough. I did attempt to have the receiver run 100% of the time and changed the enabled="true" at 1 point trying to get this thing to wake the device. The phone i am basing my testing on is running Nougat. So currently i use the receiver and enable wakelocks. Would it be better to instead do a startService command and run a service which `onStartCommand()` calls `msgReqAction()`. Would it be conceivable to say, it receives broadcast but cant perform the function being requested because it cant hold a wakelock? or am i having an issue with receiving a broadcast period

Comment: There's a lot going on there!  With Nougat, you will have issues with Doze mode to contend with.  Pre-Marshmallow, you could have your receiver take a wakelock and start your `Service`, which would do its work then release the wakelock (see `WakefulReceiver` for details.) But, with Doze mode it gets more complicated. You may wish to try and use your receiver to then schedule work via `JobScheduler`.  The work will still be "batched" during doze mode's periodic wakeup intervals, but it will at least execute.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was resolved by granting auto launch permission for the app.

Go to 
Settings->Permissions->Manage Auto Launch 
and allow auto launch for your app.